# Unable to make DNS SPF pass for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I've placed this TXT record in the DNS for domain : admissioncourses.com :

```
v=spf1 a mx mx:mail.admissioncourses.com ~all
```

Ideally all I want is that only email sent from admissioncourses.com( and it's IP) should have SPF PASS. Forged emails should not.

Anyway with this SPF I see Gmail showing the SPF as neutral or none.

What do I do to make Gmail SPF pass?

Comment: Your DNS records have an absurdly long TTL. Lower your TTL, wait a day, and try again.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it again. But this tool: http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester tells me that using the current SPF header it allows any IP to send email on behalf of admissioncourses.com. How to restrict it to be the ip of the domain only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask two different questions, one in the main body and one in your comment above.

I'll take the second of those first.  To restrict the sender to the IP of the domain only, your problem is `~all`.  That is an SPF instruction to recipients **not** to so restrict emails: it says that if the email doesn't come from one of the approved senders, they should accept it anyway.  It makes the record useless - or **worse** than useless (some sysadmins here use SPF records that don't end in `-all` as a positive indicator of spam).

So change your terminal record to `-all`, which will tell recipients that mail that doesn't come from the listed approved hosts should be rejected.  You can also lose `mx:mail.admissioncourses.com`, because that subdomain doesn't **have** an MX record.

As for the first part of your question, I can't say what will make google behave in a certain way, because they don't always publish what they do, nor how.  But fixing your terminal record may well help.

Note also that in the example above, google is receiving the email from your server via ipv6.  Since your server is ipv6-capable, it would be as well to include the ipv6 address or netblock in your SPF record explicitly, perhaps with `ip6:2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe73:2b08`.